# Any resources to learn about EOS Consensus algorithm in detail?

Tags: resources, consensus, dpos, bft-dpos

I've gone through the white paper v2 for EOS but I was wondering if there are any resources that have a detailed technical explanation of the version of the DPoS consensus algorithm used in EOS. I'm hoping to find something like a blog/video series or a book. If nothing of that sort exists can someone point me to the relevant files in the EOS git repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the official [Technical Whitepaper V2](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md), followings are the few documents which were released even before the EOS mainnet launch:-

- [EOS: an Introduction](https://eos.io/documents/EOS_An_Introduction.pdf): This describes about the way to reach DPoS consensus mechanism.
- [EOS Multi-signature](https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-multisig-tutorial): This tells you about how to ensure an account (user or contract) with multi-signature feature.
- [EOS: Explanation of DPoS+BFT w/ Daniel Larimer - Part 1 of 2](https://steemit.com/eos/@eosgo/eos-explanation-of-dpos-bft-w-daniel-larimer-part-1-of-2): This explanation is by Dan himself - part 1.
- [EOS: Explanation of New BFT+DPoS w/ Daniel Larimer - Part 2 of 2](https://steemit.com/eos/@eosgo/4izmr903): This explanation is by Dan himself - part 2.
- [DPOS Consensus Algorithm - The Missing White Paper](https://steemit.com/dpos/@dantheman/dpos-consensus-algorithm-this-missing-white-paper)
- [Last irreversible Block discussion in Github](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2718)
- [BTS DPoS Consensus Code Implementation Overview](https://blog.csdn.net/ggq89/article/details/80068306): This shows the code implementation of the DPoS consensus mechanism via code.